# how to generate random strings?

Tags: java, string, random

Here is a piece of code that I am working with, however, I want to generate random responses with regards to the strings that I have set up. How best to approach this? Perhaps just to clarify, I need my "Hello", "Good day", "bye", "farewell" to be output randomly as opposed to the order in which they are listed.

```
public void run() {
    String importantInfo[] = {
          "Hello",
          "Good day",
          "bye",
          "farewell"
    };

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < importantInfo.length; i++) {
        drop.put(importantInfo[i]);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    drop.put("DONE");
}
```

Comment: Random responses where? Each time you get an input you want a random String?

Comment: To answer the question in your question subject, here you go: `java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Comment: the importantInfo string array contains 4 possible results. But I want to generate the response randomly later in my code.

Comment: @LucasRoss only generates id like strings I think Derek is asking for strings that make sense as in readable, understandable strings? Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: how you want them to generete? do you want to your appliation generate random string of characters, chose bunch of random words from list, or pich random entry from your list?

Comment: I want to take the existing strings and output them in a random order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presuming "strings I have set up" refers to the importantInfo variable, and random response is a random item from that array: select a random number from the Random object and use this value as the index to your string array.

```
String randomString = importantInfo[random.nextInt(importantInfo.length)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Go get apache-commons for RandomUtils and call nextInt(4).

There are also random string , long, and float methods available.